# DevOps Pipeline runs whenever main branch changes, rather than on desired schedule

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following DevOps pipeline:

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 6 * * Mon"
  displayName: Monday Morning World Build
  branches:
    include:
    - main

stages:
  - template: ./pipeline-review.yml

... other stuff that's probably not important
```

However, this pipeline automatically runs whenever the `main` branch changes.  What I want is for this pipeline to *only* run every Monday at 6am.  Anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured this out.  By default, DevOps includes a CI/CD trigger on all branches.  You need to disable this:

```
trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "0 6 * * Mon"
  displayName: Monday Morning World Build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
```

It's annoying how absolutely no documentation or blog I found mentioned this.  I guess everyone assumes you want CI/CD *and* the scheduled trigger.

Comment: Hi, Mike, thanks for your post and kindly sharing. To benefit more developers and users, you could highlight this solution to help them with the similar scenario.

Comment: `trigger: main` to the source repo where the yaml file locates is set by default when you create a new yaml pipeline. So we always need to set to `none` in our daily test. You could also create a [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest?) for this update.

Comment: @CeenoQi-MSFT Honestly I just think this should be documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).  Perhaps in the example schedule trigger code, they should have a `trigger: none` to indicate they are disabling the default branch related triggers.